# Flutter Speech to text listening continuously

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

Please how i can implement Flutter Speech to text listening continuously
without typing in a button to start

Please give some suggestion about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter speech to text doesn't allow continuous listening because of privacy issue :(